# macro for reading workbook rows, reading each cell and populate text value in last column

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering if someone could help me on an item. We have a daily report that has many rows of data.

I need to read each row and values in Columns P,Q,R,S

If row value in P, is bold then move on to column Q, if column Q row value is bold, move on to R column, if column R row value is not bold, then take that column name and insert in column Q and that row value.

Thank you!

Jennifer

Comment: Welcome to SO Jennifer. To get quick answers, you need to show what you have tried so that people can help you fix the exact error rather than coding the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

This probably close...  You will have to play with it.

```
Sub junk()
     Dim x As Integer
  ' Set numrows = number of rows of data.
  NumRows = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
  ' Select cell a1.
  Range("P1").Select
  ' Establish "For" loop to loop "numrows" number of times.
  For x = 1 To NumRows

     If (ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True) Then
        Range("Q" + x).Select
         If (ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True) Then
             Range("R" + x).Select
            If (ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True) Then
                        Range("T" + x).Select
                        If (ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True) Then

                        End If
             End If
         End If
     End If


  Next

End Sub
```